# Deliver test params using adb shell am start command

Tags: android, shell, adb

- I wish to know how in java I should receive these parameters.
- I do know how to deliver parameters via adb shell am start command but I still have a
  problem to get them in java (android) code.

My class extends InstrumentationTestCase and not Activity class!!!

So I cannot perform: this.getIntent().

I anderstand that I need to create intent doing: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.someAction);

Can you help me to find out what action should I use here.

I also read that there are secondary attributes: category, type, component, extras. I know that I also need to update the manifest file accordingly. Sorry for so many q/a.

Thanks a lot for your assist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "adb shell am" for several things:
- manually start activities using intents
- manually broadcast intents (for broadcastreceivers mostly)
- start an Instrumentation
- ...

It seems most of your question is about the concept Intent. It would be good to read upon that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class that extends `InstrumentationTestRunner`,
2. Override the method `onCreate(Bundle args)`, and
3. configure your `AndroidManifest.xml` to use this new runner.